# How to cut and paste from Remote Desktop Viewer

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I use rdesktop to access a Windows XP box at work, and I use "Remote Desktop Viewer" to access a Mac OS X box with vnc.  Cut and paste works ok from rdesktop, although occasionally I have to kill and restart the rdpclip.exe program on the Windows box to unstick it.  But how do I cut and paste between the Remote Desktop Viewer session and the host?